# PHP: Keep array filled

Tags: php, arrays, forms

Each time I press `addproduct` button my array is emptied. I assume that is because of the `$productarray = array();` declaration, but I want to keep what I've added into it each time. So, if I press `addproduct` twice, I want first entry to stay intact. I will have another button that redirects the user to next page but before that clears the array;

```
$productarray = array();
if(isset($_POST['addproduct'])){
  $prod = trim(mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['prodcall']))));
  array_push($productarray,$prod);
}
print_r($productarray);
```

Looking for a way that hopefully does not need to use SQLDB or SESSION.

Comment: Data does not persist between PHP calls. You are not storing the array anywhere, so the data is not retained. You ***need*** a session or database or other permanent storage!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the execution of script completes, all variables declared are destructed by itself. As an alternate to this you can take advantage of Session variable `$_SESSION` or a Temporary table in database. JavaScript can also help if you change it to a button rather than a submit button.